# Agora WebRTC Change video call view

Tags: react-native, webrtc, agora.io

I am working on a react-native project which uses Agora.io for video calling.
In a video call it shows my camera feed as fullscreen and the reciever's feed as thumbnail which is the opposite of the correct way.

I want to know, Is this the way agora works or is it possible to fix this..?
Because even in their website they have put the images in that way.

[image on the home page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rWE2.jpg)

I appreciate any help regarding to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are presenting the local video stream to the larger view. You would need to switch this. Render the remote video stream on the larger view and the local video stream on the thumbnail view.